# Presenting ngModel inside text input

Tags: angular, typescript, ngmodel

I'm having troubles with presenting data inside input forms.

```
 <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text text-white" style="background-color:#03a9f4">Product ID</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="productID" name="productID" readonly="true" style="background-color: white">
 </div>
```

Inside `component.ts` i got

```
 private productID: string;

  private initData() {
    this.productID = "12345"; //TODO REST call for data
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initData();
  }
```

But for some reason, my input has no value on page load. Why is that?

Comment: Have you imported the `FormsModule`? Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Yes, I got `FormsModule` inside my `app.module.ts` and in component I'm testing. There are no errors in console.

Comment: Can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Could the text in the input be white on a white background? If you double-click in the input element, is anything selected?

Comment: You need to call `initData()` below the `ngOnInit()` show my answer I have created a `stackblitz` for you.

Comment: `FormsModule` should go in `imports` in module and has nothing to do in component

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created a stackblitz for you and it is working.
I have copied your code please check it again.

[Working Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3nivv)